# Can you change the color assigned in an XML drawable after compile?

Tags: java, xml

My team is creating a small child app that wants the user to match shapes and/or colors. We have a main_shape, a correct_shape, and garbage_shape1 / garbage_shape2 that displays on the screen. The shapes are determined at runtime randomly and loaded to the activity to display to the user. Right now each shape is an XML drawable and has a hard coded color. (A red circle, a yellow star, a blue square, ect). [Here is an image of the game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3un3b.jpg)

My question is this:

is there anyway to change the color of the shapes programically? So lets say I wanted to change each shapes color to blue: a blue circle, another blue circle, triangle, and star, all blue? Is there a way to do that in Java; edit an xml attribute?

We have all the shapes in a stack of lists:

```java
ShapeBuilder shapeBuilder = new ShapeBuilder(gameMode);
        Stack<List<Shape>> stackOfShapes = shapeBuilder.getStackofShapes();

        //gather first round and assign to activity
        List<Shape> round = stackOfShapes.pop();

_mainShape.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
```

Then we are trying to assign a color and we have tried this so far trying to assign the _mainShape of circle to the color blue: (however I have the feeling this is the wrong road to do down)

```
Drawable background = _mainShape.getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue));
        } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue));
        } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue));
        }
```

I'm trying to see if we can change the XML file from this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200"/> <!-- red, to blue -->
    <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

I do apologize this is my first question and therefore probably very poorly written, but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: it would help seeing some code. Otherwise people most likely wont help you on that. And while saying that, its also useful if people see that you tried something before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```